# Jupyter-Lite modules/packages/libraries install

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How do I add more modules in Jupyter-Lite?
ive tried most variations.

and does Jupyter-Lite use the python libraries on my machine?

I expected Jupyer-lite in the browser to use my python libraries installed locally , like in , Jupyter-lab if I issued the import command in Jupyyer-lite to import them in

Answer (score 6):

JupyterLite cannot really see your system files due to the browser sandboxing it runs in. (In fact, one of the big things being focused on is making it possible to interact better with local storage.) Therefore, it cannot use your libraries installed locally at this time. (Not to mention, they wouldn't be compiled on your system to use webassembly and thus incompatible.)

A lot of the modules in the Python data science stack has already been converted to WebAssembly support.
You can see example of how to install several of these exploring the example notebooks in the `pyolite` directory available from [here](https://jupyterlite.github.io/demo/retro/tree/).
You use `piplite` which is a wrapper around [`micropip`](https://test-pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pypi.html). (`piplite` being a wrapper is stated here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/using.html).)

Here's how it is suggested to install several **at this time**:

```py
import piplite
await piplite.install('numpy')
await piplite.install('pandas')
await piplite.install('matplotlib')
await piplite.install('bokeh')
```

This is a rapidly developing ecosystem, and so it helps to keep following the updates in [a thread at the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlite-jupyter-webassembly-python/9939/4?u=fomightez). Following [Jeremy Tuloup on Twitter](https://twitter.com/jtpio) is highly recommended as well.

---

*Usage tip*
Note that I refer to a current site offering JupyterLite [here](https://jupyterlite.github.io/demo/retro/tree/). If you fear you may have already accessed this page and edited some and lost track which are the official versions of the notebooks vs. those you edited, a nice trick is to access the site in an incognito window on your computer. Those windows won't be linked to your browser cache for that site and so you get a 'clean' version of what is currently available from the location.