# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'piplite'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a Jupiter file, please note I'm new to python.

following is first code block which fails within Jupiter, I'm using it with Vscode.

```py
# Dependency needed to install file 

# If running the notebook on your machine, else leave it commented
#!pip install xlrd

#!pip install openpyxl 
import piplite
await piplite.install(['xlrd','openpyxl'])
```

[image]
Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\..\Projects\python\ibm_backend\PY0101EN-4-3-LoadData.jupyterlite.ipynb Cell 7 line 7
      1 # Dependency needed to install file 
      2 
      3 # If running the notebook on your machine, else leave it commented
      4 #!pip install xlrd
      5 
      6 #!pip install openpyxl 
----> 7 import piplite
      8 await piplite.install(['xlrd','openpyxl'])

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'piplite'
```

Also Im using virtual environment.

```
 pip -V
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\..\Projects\python\ibm_backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)
py -m ensurepip
Looking in links: c:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1lqhflza
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\..\projects\python\ibm_backend\.venv\lib\site-packages (65.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\..\projects\python\ibm_backend\.venv\lib\site-packages (23.1.2)
```

Comment: Did you forget to install `piplite`? What's the output of `python -m pip freeze | grep -i piplite`? You could also remove the `piplite.install()` calls and just install with `pip` from the comand line: `python -m pip install xlrd openpyxl`.

Comment: @MichaelRuth im on windows. sorry forgot to mention this. I tried install pip install piplite its not found

Comment: It looks like `piplite` is a Jupyter thing. Try the second option I suggested, using appropriate syntax for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @MichaelRuth in earlier comments `piplite` is Jupyter notebook extension or lib not available outside in Vscode environment. as of now, remove piplite from code useage works.

Comment: For further background, `piplite` was for a while the way to install things with pip in JupyterLite, see example [featuring it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71712055/8508004). (JupyterLite uses Web Assembly to allow Jupyter to run inside a user's browser.) Note that is no longer the case, as the JupyterLite developers added the use of the magic `%pip install` command to make it consistent with typical, **modern** Jupyter.